# In the A* Search Algorithm, why do we add g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue

[Per the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

> ...f(n) = g(n) + h(n)
>
> where n is the last node on the path, g(n) is the cost of the path from the start node to n, and h(n) is a heuristic that estimates the cost of the cheapest path from n to the goal.

Why do we consider the cost of the path from the start node to where we currently are? I have been playing around with implementing this algorithm for a problem, and have been using a priority queue and when I do g(n) + h(n) it takes longer than just using strictly h(n). Wouldn't it make sense to only use h(n) since hypothetically if the heuristic is accurate you only care about how close you are to your goal?

EDIT: Actually I just discovered that my g(n) function was computing wrong, but I still logically don't really understand why g(n) + h(n) would be better than just h(n).

Comment: You may get incorrect results otherwise. Take for example the perfectly valid heuristic h(n)=0.

Comment: Well, the total cost from start to goal is the cost from start -> n + the cost from n -> goal. That is, `S -> G = S -> n + n -> G = g(n) + h(n)`.

Comment: You might want to remove the [java] tag since this is language agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to see why leaving out g(n) leads to an incorrect algorithm is the fact that the real costs would never enter the algorithm. It relies totally on the heuristic, which is only guaranteed to be a lower bound.

Comment: True, since h(n) is just an estimate we are just relying on our own estimates if we are not using g(n). Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Greedy search algorithms use ***f(n)=h(n)*** and for this reason they are non-complete algorithms (in other words, it does not guarantee to find the solution). In fact you were describing *Hill Climbing Algorithm*.